# increment not working in controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, controller

```
    $scope.isChecked = function(id){              
    var i=0,j=0,k=0;
    //$scope.abc[i].usertype[j].keywords[0].key_bool=true;
    if($scope.abc[i].type_selected == true){
        while($scope.abc[i].usertype.length){
            while($scope.abc[i].usertype[j].keywords.length){
                if($scope.abc[i].usertype[j].keywords[k]._id == id){
                    if($scope.abc[i].usertype[j].keywords[k].key_bool == true){
                        $scope.abc[i].usertype[j].keywords[k].key_bool = false;
                        return false;
                    }
                    else{
                        $scope.abc[i].usertype[j].keywords[k].key_bool = true;
                        return true;
                    }                        
                }
                k++;
            }
            j++;
        }
    }
};
```

Incrementing k++ is working while incrementing j++ not, can someone explain me this, why such happening?

isChecked function called whenever checkbox is checked/unchecked as:

```
ng-click="isChecked(l._id)"
```

Everything works perfectly for 'j=0', but not for later 'j' values.

Answer (score 0):

Simply because of the return statements execution gets out of the function every time a return statement is reached. So j++; is unreachable every time the if statement is executed

Comment: plz see the question properly.

Comment: @AvinashSharma what is your exact problem?  well what am telling you is true j++ only executes the outer loop as long as you never get into the inner if statements maybe am not getting you. what is the question exactly?

Comment: I want the value of 'j' to be incremented as well.
As for j=0, i m getting my answer, but with j=1,2,,....., it didn't even capturing the value of 'j'.

Answer (score 0):

for `j=0`, it goes inside the inner `while loop`, and when it reaches to the return statement, it comes out of function.

That is why, `outer while loop` is not getting executed again.

To get more about `return`, [read this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return)

Comment: plz see the question properly.

Answer (score 0):

i got the answer.
we have to put k=0; between the 2 while loops.
still thanks guys for ur help